# Using viewForOverlay to return an MKOverlayView but I also need to return an MKCircleRenderer in the same method

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkcircle

I have an `MKMapView` that I need to display two types of overlay on. One is a tiled overlay that I use a subclass of `MKOverlayView` and an `MKCircleRenderer`.

My method is:
`- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay` but now I need to also render an `MKCircle` I'm getting an compiler error of:
'Incompatible pointer types returning 'MKCircleRenderer *' from a function with result type 'MKOverlayView * _Nonnull'.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]]) {
        MKCircleRenderer *circleView = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
        return circleView;
    } else {
        TileOverlayView *view = [[TileOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        view.tileAlpha = 1.0;
        return view;
    }
}
```

That is my code, I'm aware that `initWithOverlay` is deprecated which I'm working on as another issue.

Comment: Can you make your tile view a `MKOverlayRenderer` rather that an overlay view? Then you could implement `rendererForOverlay` rather than `viewForOverlay` And then you can return both renderers from a single method.

Comment: Great help! Thanks @Rob! I just made my `TileOverlayView` a subclass of `MKOverlayRenderer` and it's all working great! If you want to submit as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the tile view is apparently subclassing from `MKOverlayView` (returned by `viewForOverlay`), whereas `MKCircleRenderer` subclasses from the more modern `MKCircleRenderer`, a subclass of `MKOverlayRenderer` (returned by `rendererForOverlay`), not of `MKOverlayView`.

I'd suggest that you can make your tile view a `MKOverlayRenderer` subclass rather than an overlay view. That way, rather than `viewForOverlay`, you can implement `rendererForOverlay` and return either circle renderer or tile renderer.